# OKta + react native + OKta custom login page + okta login in offline

Tags: ios, react-native, okta

I have a react native ios app to which I have integrated OKTA but I also need a OKTA custom login page directly in my app so that the user will not redirect to okta page to login.

Can I use `@okta/okta-signin-widget` for integrating login page into my native app or any other packages/dependencies should I download and also can we make a user login in to okta when he is not connected with internet.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve haven't tried integrating the Sign-In Widget with React Native, but I have tried its underlying library — Okta’s Auth SDK — in Ionic. It doesn’t work because it tries to create an iframe to make a request and this doesn’t work in a native mobile app. I have written a blog post about how to integrate Okta with React Native: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/16/build-react-native-authentication-oauth-2

Comment: Infact i have developed my app referring to your blog...and can i make a user login into okta when he is in offline mode

Comment: You won’t be able to login if you’re offline. However, if you’ve logged in and your access token isn’t expired, you should stay logged in. If you’re developing a progressive web app, you can cache the network response from Okta and resolve from the cache if the user is offline. I’m not sure if RN allows you to use a service worker to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Can I use my react native  applications login page to enter user credentials instead of custom login page provided by okta..

Comment: Yes. See https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react-native/tree/master/custom-sign-in.